# Shell Scripting to find difference in time for particular scenario

Tags: performance, bash, shell, awk

Need help to find time difference(only seconds) between "WAM1" and "WAM2" recent consecutive launch in below /var/log/messages

WAM1 launched at `2013-07-09T02:20:10.735639Z` and `2013-07-09T02:20:12.635639Z` so now recent one for WAM2 is `2013-07-09T02:20:12.635639Z` so difference between `(15.84675 - 12.635639)= 3.211111` is the results in seconds

```
2013-07-09T02:20:10.735639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:11.817372Z user.info sam SAM 
2013-07-09T02:20:12.635639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:13.817372Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:14.818442Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:15.846751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:16.846636Z user.info sam SAM 
2013-07-09T02:20:16.848751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2 
2013-07-09T02:20:17.851727Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:18.935639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:19.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:20.817372Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:22.746751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM
```

The Below Program gives wrong result for above log messages

```
$ awk '
/WAM1/{ split($1,start,/[:Z]/); wam1[++i]=start[3] }
/WAM2/{ split($1,stop,/[:Z]/); wam2[++j]=stop[3] }
END   { len=i>j?i:j; for(;x<len;) 
print "Delta "++x" = "wam2[x]-wam1[x] }' /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Please post the desired output! And try to you use sample input and output that cover as many corner cases as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
awk '/WAM1/{ split($1,start,/[:Z]/); wam1=start[3] }
/WAM2/{ split($1,stop,/[:Z]/); wam2=stop[3]; print "Delta "++x" = "wam2-wam1}' 1
```

This code yields:

```
Delta 1 = 3.21111
Delta 2 = 4.21311
Delta 3 = 3.21111
```

Another code:

```
awk '/WAM1/{ split($1,start,/[:Z]/); wam1=start[3]; i=1; }
/WAM2/{ split($1,stop,/[:Z]/); wam2=stop[3]; if (i==1) print "Delta "++x" = "wam2-wam1; i=0;}' 1
```

yields:

```
Delta 1 = 3.21111
Delta 2 = 3.21111
```

Comment: but Delta 2 is taking Delta 1'S WAM1 value , in this sceneraio only 2 delta values should results not 3 delta values.

Comment: @Santosh, I added an another version.